# hosting nodejs applications using nginx in ec2 AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf file 
in http section, given the below informaiton.

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

/etc/nginx/conf.d/myapp.conf file content

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name _;
        index index.html index.htm;


        location  / {

               proxy_pass 'http://XXXXX:3005/';
        }

         location /admin/ {

                proxy_pass 'http://XXXX:3000/';
        }

}
```

http://XXXX is redirecting to the main page.
http://xxxxx/admin/ is not redirecting. Instead it is throwing below errors in chrome console.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9iZ3.png)

The same site is working fine http://xxxx:3000 it is working fine. No issues.

Whatelse am I missing?

Note: OS is Amazon Linux & I have tested the same configuration with sample help world node js program & it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your routing is correct and that you have restarted nginx after configuration.

Try the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS:3005;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /admin {
        proxy_pass http://APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```